# How to filter empty groups from a reduction?

Tags: crossfilter

It appears to me that Crossfilter never excludes a group from the results of a reduction, even if the applied filters have excluded all the rows in that group.  Groups that have had all of their rows filtered out simply return an aggregate value of 0 (or whatever `reduceInitial` returns).

The problem with this is that it makes it impossible to distinguish between groups that contain no rows and groups that do contain rows but just legitimately aggregate to a value of 0.  Basically, there's no way (that I can see) to distinguish between a null value and a 0 aggregation.

Does anybody know of a built-in Crossfilter technique for achieving this? I did come up with a way to do this with my own custom `reduceInitial/reduceAdd/reduceRemove` method but it wasn't totally straight forward and it seemed to me that this is behavior that might/should be more native to Crossfilter's filtering semantics.  So I'm wondering if there's a canonical way to achieve this.

I'll post my technique as an answer if it turns out that there is no built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this is to have both count and total be reduce attributes:

```
var dimGroup = dim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  ++p.count;
  p.total += v.value;
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  --p.count;
  p.total -= v.value;
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {count: 0, total: 0};
}
```

Empty groups will have zero counts, so retrieving only non-empty groups is easy:

```
dimGroup.top(Infinity).filter(function(d) { return d.value.count > 0; });
```

Comment: This is really great. After seeing your answer it became obvious that the structure I was using to keep count was exactly mirroring the group structure itself.  Sticking the count into the reduction result is a fantastic idea.  Nice one!

Comment: I was looking to learn why a crossfilter group was not returning the filtered set but your answer @davidshinn helped me solve the problem. For others who may be searching for the same question I was see a [possible dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212411/crossfilter-group-not-returning-filtered-set) of this question.

Comment: This will achieve the correct result, but it is not efficient because you have to filter on every element in the group.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there doesn't seem to be any obvious answer jumping out so I'll answer my own question and post the technique I used to solve this.

This example assumes that I've already created a dimension and grouping, which is passed in as `groupDim`.  Because I want to be able to sum up any arbitrary numeric field, I also pass in `fieldName` so that it will be available in the closure scope of my the reduction functions.

One important characteristic of this technique is that it relies on there being a way to uniquely identify which group each row belongs to.  Thinking in term of OLAP, this is essentially the "tuple" that defines a particular aggregation context.  But it can be anything you want as long as it deterministically returns the same value for all data rows belonging to a given group.

The end result is that empty groups will have an aggregate value of "null" which can be easily detected for and filtered out after the fact.  Any group with at least one row will have a numeric value (even if it happens to be zero).

Refinements or suggestions to this are more then welcome.  Here's the code with comments inline:

```
function configureAggregateSum(groupDim, fieldName) {

    function getGroupKey(datum) {
        // Given datum return key corresponding to the group to which the datum belongs
    }

    // This object will keep track of the number of times each group had reduceAdd
    // versus reduceRemove called. It is used to revert the running aggregate value
    // back to "null" if the count hits zero. This is unfortunately necessary because
    // Crossfilter filters as it is aggregating so reduceAdd can be called even if, in
    // the end, all records in a group end up being filtered out.
    //
    var groupCount = {};

    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
        // Here's the code that keeps track of the invocation count per group
        var groupKey = getGroupKey(v);
        if (groupCount[groupKey] === undefined) { groupCount[groupKey] = 0; }
        groupCount[groupKey]++;

        // And here's the implementation of the add reduction (sum in my case)
        // Note the check for null (our initial value)
        var value = +v[fieldName];
        return p === null ? value : p + value;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
        // This code keeps track of invocations of invocation count per group and, importantly,
        // reverts value back to "null" if it hits 0 for the group. Essentially, if we detect
        // that group has no records again we revert to the initial value.
        var groupKey = getGroupKey(v);
        groupCount[groupKey]--;
        if (groupCount[groupKey] === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // And here's the code for the remove reduction (sum in my case)
        var value = +v[fieldName];
        return p - value;
    }

    function reduceInitial() {
        return null;
    }

    // Once returned, can invoke all() or top() to get the values, which can then be filtered
    // using a native Array.filter to remove the groups with null value.
    return groupedDim.reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
}
```