# crossfilter group not returning filtered set

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

My data looks like this:

```
[{timestamp:1213240000,mag:6,pressure:50,duration:30},
 {timestamp:1213250000,mag:6.4,pressure:50,duration:5},
 {timestamp:1213260000,mag:5.9,pressure:50,duration:14},
 {timestamp:1213270000,mag:4.3,pressure:50,duration:6}]
```

My dimensions are:

```
var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.timestamp});
var magDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.mag});
```

My filter:

```
dateDim.filter([1213250000,1213260000]);
```

My group:

```
var grp = magDim.group();
```

Unfortunately,

```
console.log(grp.all());
console.log(grp.top(Infinity));
```

> Gives me entire dataset, not respecting my filter.

however,

```
console.log(magDim.top(Infinity));
```

> Works fine. I get the filtered data

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamjab/paftztyL/

I want to get only the filtered set. How can I remove the entries with *Value:0*

Thanks.

Comment: What do you actually get back from grp.top(Infinity)? I think you'll see all keys, but only groups with keys 6.4 and 5.9 should have a value of 1. The others should have values of 0. Also, you have a typo in your magDim definition, but I expect that's not in your actual code or nothing would work.

Comment: yes, this is not the actual code. and I see the typo. I expected to get a subset of the actual data that satisfies the filter. Is that wrong assumption?

Comment: I see that it does filter, by setting value 0 to those that are not satisfying the  filter. How can I get an array only values > 0. Using crossfilter that is, I don't want to loop over it (performance) as the dataset is huge.

Comment: grp.top(Infinity) will not be a huge array if your magnitude is only to 2 significant figures. Just use the .filter method on the array to filter out the groups you aren't interested in, in this case groups where value === 0.